# Is finding a key in a dictionary takes the same time as finding an item in a list

Tags: python, list, performance, dictionary, big-o

I have a dictionary with `1,000,000` keys, I want to check if a certain key exists in a dictionary.
I could also have `1,000,000` items in a list which would hold all of those keys.

Which is the faster way and why?

For example:

```
999999 in {x:x for x in range(1000000)}
```

vs

```
999999 in [x for x in range(1000000)]
```

Comment: No, by definition. A dict lookup is O(1) (ignoring hash collisions), a list lookup is O(N) https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: if you are using jupyter notebook, you can use %%timeit to find out for yourself.

Comment: It seems you are comparing both the time to create the collections and the time to search them. Is that what you intended? *Creating* the list is faster, but *searching* the dict is faster.

Comment: @MarkMeyer actually it doesn't look like OP timed anything, they just threw some code on SO (they ask which one is faster. If they timed themselves they would have known the answer)

Comment: "Which is the faster way" Did you *test it*? "and why" did you try putting `dict vs list lookup performance` into a search engine?

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries are faster because keys are hashed. See here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Adding to what @leo said, the reason it might seem that it takes quite some time in both cases, is because you check both at creation time. first create the dictionary and list separately and then check the time it took to execute each one of them.

Comment: Agreed. My answer refers to the lookup only